# Edition with 1-hour episodes each of TV series 24?

Tags: alternate-version, 24

I wonder if there's a DVD release or similar of the TV series 24, in which each episode lasts one hour.

What they showed on TV was only ever 42 minutes of the series, and the rest being used for commercial breaks.

Is there some kind of special edition, in which you see ~5 minutes of split screen instead of what they used for commercials?

Comment: What would you put in the additional ~18 minutes?

Comment: As I said, I expected long split screen scenes in the DVD home edition. Of course with nothing essential happening during that period, just a few minutes to "silently" follow the simultanous actions.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a shopping question

Comment: @DForck42 Not really, it's a pretty genuine distribution question based on the specific real-time format of the TV-show. Noone wants to locate anything here, it asks if such a thing was ever made for the TV-show.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No.  Commercial breaks happened (presumably) during mundane events or periods of inactivity.  The clock would pick up again when they returned from commercial break.  The clock never ended at 42:00, it always ended at 60:00.

Answer (score 3):

No. TV producers don't shoot more material to fill time on DVD releases that would normally go to commercials.